# Routing Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm making a movie site and when I click on the image to redirect to the movie page, I've already managed to do this, but to work I'm having to put several :id/:id/:id in app.routing.
If I just put a :id it appears that it is changing the route but it doesn't load other movies.
I've seen sites that do this more correctly but I couldn't make it work without several :id

```js
*** COMPONENT HEADER TS *****
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.tmdb.getSeries().subscribe(data => {
      this.series = data;
      const min = 0;
      const max = this.series.results.length - 1;
      this.randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
      this.headerBGUrl = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original' + this.series.results[this.randomNumber].backdrop_path;
      this.image = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w100' + this.series.results[this.randomNumber].poster_path;
      let description = this.series.results[this.randomNumber].overview;
      if (description.length > 300) {
        description = description.substring(0, 300)+'...';
      };
      this.overview = description
      this.id = this.series.results[this.randomNumber].id
    })
```

```css
*** COMPONENT HEADER HTML *****

<div class="container" *ngIf="headerBGUrl; else loading">
  <div class="header">
    <div
      class="header__banner"
      [ngStyle]="{
        'background-size': 'cover',
        'background-position': 'top center',
        'background-image': 'url(' + headerBGUrl + ')'
      }">
      <div class="featured--horizontal">
        <div class="featured--vertical"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="info">
        <div class="title">
          <h2>{{ this.series.results[this.randomNumber].name }}</h2>
          <span class="points">Nota: </span>
          <span class="points">{{
            this.series.results[this.randomNumber].vote_average }}</span>
          <span>{{
            this.series.results[this.randomNumber].first_air_date | date: "yyyy"
          }}</span>
        </div>
        <p>{{ this.overview }}</p>
        <div class="info-btns">
          <a href="{{ this.key }}">
          <button class="watchButton">► Assistir</button></a>
          <button class="listButton">+ Minha Lista</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div
      class="header__main"
      id="stickyHeader"
      [class.sticky]="sticky"
      #stickHeader
    >
      <div class="header__left">
        <a routerLink="/">
          <img src="assets/img/netflix.svg" alt="logo" />
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="header__right">
        <img
          src="https://occ-0-4345-3647.1.nflxso.net/dnm/api/v6/Z-WHgqd_TeJxSuha8aZ5WpyLcX8/AAAABRGTK96GBeqNw5zzYXnoa8oVjSjhuk7SuseuKTmgEKwpcCB59994UWb6wd7d1WONZOuzJwbLNpzG5Okfo4rSDLg.png?r=ee6"
          alt="avatar"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<ng-template #loading>
  <mat-spinner [color]="color" style="margin: 80px auto"></mat-spinner>
</ng-template>




****** routerlink *****

            <div class="img carousel-cell" *ngFor="let m of movies.results">
              <img
                routerLink="{{ m.id }}"
                src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w200{{ m?.poster_path }}"
                alt="{{ m.title }}"
              />
            </div>
```

```html
APP.ROUTING !!!
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: "", redirectTo:"home", pathMatch:"full"},
  {path: "home", component: HomeComponent},
  {path: ":id", component: OverviewComponent},
  {path: ":id/:id", component: OverviewComponent},
  {path: ":id/:id/:id", component: OverviewComponent},
  {path: ":id/:id/:id/:id", component: OverviewComponent},
  {path: ":id/:id/:id/:id/:id", component: OverviewComponent},
  {path: "**", redirectTo:"home"}
];
```

Comment: You should change the parameters name, :id/:id/:id how to know which :id it will take?
For example, change for :movie/:actor/:rating/:anythin...

Comment: I did the test this way and it won't, the id changes, but the content is not loaded. I uploaded a gif to show "imgur.com/HGGsGLh", I did the test the way you showed me and then with the route":id/:id/:id"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should subscribe to activatedRoute.params, check:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kwqbgg?file=src/app/router-params/router-params.component.ts

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.activetedRouter.params.subscribe(params => {
      console.log('params', params);
    });
  }
```

It will run to each router params change.

Answer (score 0):

phu.. it's really hard to find out what's going on here.
I guess it's because you need an absolute routerLink.
Please try to replace

```
routerLink="{{ m.id }}"
```

with

```
routerLink="/{{ m.id }}"
```

Ok.. this was the first step. Now, that you have only one Route loading the same component, this component is not recreated every time the url changes. So ngOnInit() is only called the first time (or if you reload the page e.g. using F5).

So you have to listen to the changes yourself:

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute){ }

ngOnInit() {
      this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
          // load data with id = params.id;
      })
}
```

Comment: I did the test this way and it won't, the id changes, but the content is not loaded.
I uploaded a gif to show "https://imgur.com/HGGsGLh", I did the test the way you showed me and then with the route":id/:id/:id"

Comment: I extended my answer. Hope this will solve your issues.

Comment: It should be `activatedRoute.params` it seems to `activatedRoute.data` is static. https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#data

Comment: Thanks.. I changed that. I actually did not check my code ;-)